# Does it matter where you put the linktoseries parameter in a strategy() or study() in Pine Script on TradingView?

Tags: pine-script

Hello all and thanks in advance!

I am just learning Pine Script and have been going over how to setup the `strategy()` and `study()` functions. One that that has got me is that in the documentation and the errors in the console it doesn't seem to have a spot for the `linktoseries` parameter. It does explain what it is in the documentation but when they give you both functions it is missing and it is also missing in the error message that lists out the types in the overload it is looking for.

Here is the strategy
`strategy(title, shorttitle, overlay, format, precision, scale, pyramiding, calc_on_order_fills, calc_on_every_tick, max_bars_back, backtest_fill_limits_assumption, default_qty_type, default_qty_value, initial_capital, currency, max_lines_count, max_labels_count, slippage, commission_type, commission_value, process_orders_on_close, close_entries_rule)`

Here is the study
`study(title, shorttitle, overlay, format, precision, scale, max_bars_back, max_lines_count, max_labels_count, resolution, resolution_gaps)`

I have removed `linktoseries = isLinkToSeries` from my code below because I am not sure where it should go. If I just stick it on the end of the fucntions it doesn't seem to cause any issues but I am not sure if that will in the future, just does nothing, or if that is the correct spot for it.

Here is my code I used to help me learn these two functions.

Thanks again for the help and have a good one!

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © lavick81
// @version=4

// ****Default Strategy Settings****
scriptLongTitle = "Lavick81's Custom RSI Strategy or Study" // Type String
scriptShortTitle = "Lavick81's Custom RSI Strategy or Study" // Type String
isOverlayEnabled = true // Type bool. If true the study will be added as an overlay for the main series. If false - it would be added on a separate chart pane. Default is false.
typeOfFormat = format.inherit // Type string. Type of formatting study values on the price axis. Possible values are: format.inherit, format.price, format.volume. Default is format.inherit.
typeOfPrecision = 4 // Type integer. Number of digits after the floating point for study values on the price axis. Must be a non negative integer and not greater than 16. Default is 4
priceScale = 2 // Type integer. Price scale that the indicator should be attached to. Possible values are: scale.right, scale.left, scale.none. Value scale.none can be applied only in combination with 'isOverlayEnabled=true' setting. If omitted, using scale from main series.
maxPyramiding = 0 // Type integer. The maximum number of entries allowed in the same direction. If the value is 0, only one entry order in the same direction can be opened, and additional entry orders are rejected. The default value is 0.
calcOnOrderFills = false // Type bool. Additional one time intrabar order calculation. If the parameter is set to 'true', then the strategy is recalculated once intrabar after an order is filled (not only at close of the bar). The default value is 'false'.
calcOnEveryTick = false // Type bool. Additional intrabar strategy calculations. If the parameter is 'true', then the strategy will calculate on every tick in real-time, rather than on bars' closes. The parameter does not affect strategy calculation on historical data. The default value is 'false'.
maxBarsBack = 1000 // Type integer. Maximum number of bars available for a strategy for historical reference.
backtestFillLimitsAssumption = 0 // Type integer. Limit order execution assumption. Limit orders are filled intrabar only if market price exceeds the limit order level by the specified number of ticks.
defaultQtyType = strategy.cash // Type string. The allowed values are: strategy.fixed (fixed quantity by default), strategy.cash (specified in currency of the symbol and the amount is converted into quantity), strategy.percent_of_equity (% of currently available equity).
defaultQtyValue = 100.00 // Type float. Number of contracts/shares/lots/units if 'defaultQtyType'=strategy.fixed is used; or amount of cash in currency of the symbol if 'defaultQtyType'=strategy.cash is used; or number of percents of currently available equity if 'defaultQtyType'=strategy.percent_of_equity is used.
defaultInitialCapital = 10000.00 // Type float. This argument sets the strategy's initial capital, which is the capital used by the script when backtesting and forward testing on real-time data.
defaultCurrency = "USD" // Type string. Possible values are: NONE, USD, EUR, AUD, GBP, NZD, CAD, CHF, HKD, JPY, NOK, SEK, SGD, TRY, ZAR
maxLinesCount = 50 // Type integer. 0 to 500
maxLabelsCount = 50 // Type integer. 0 to 500
defaultSlippage = 0 // Type integer. Slippage in ticks to be added to/subtracted from the fill price of buy/sell market or stop orders. If mintick=0.01 and slippage=5, the amount of slippage will be 5*0.01=0.05.
defaultCommissionType = strategy.commission.percent // Type string. The allowed values are: strategy.commission.percent (a percentage of the cash volume of order), strategy.commission.cash_per_contract (money displayed in the account currency per contract), strategy.commission.cash_per_order (money displayed in the account currency per order).
defaultCommissionValue = 0.075 // Type float. Can be percent or money depending on defaultCommissionType setting
processOrderOnClose = false // Type bool. Default is false
closeEntriesRule = "FIFO" // Type string. "FIFO" (First-in, First-out) or "ANY" (Any Order)
isLinkToSeries = false // Type bool. If true then the study will be always on the same pane and same price scale as the main series. Should be true only in combination with 'isOverlayEnabled = true'


// ****Strategy OR Study****
// To make this script a strategy comment out the lines between ">>>>Study Settings Begains<<<<" and ">>>>Study Settings Ends<<<<"
// To make this script a study comment out the lines between ">>>>Strategy Settings Begains<<<<" and ">>>>Strategy Settings Ends<<<<"

// >>>>Strategy Settings Begains<<<<
strategy(title = scriptLongTitle, shorttitle = scriptShortTitle, overlay = isOverlayEnabled, format = typeOfFormat, precision = typeOfPrecision, scale = priceScale, pyramiding = maxPyramiding, calc_on_order_fills = calcOnOrderFills, calc_on_every_tick = calcOnEveryTick, max_bars_back = maxBarsBack, backtest_fill_limits_assumption = backtestFillLimitsAssumption, default_qty_type = defaultQtyType, default_qty_value = defaultQtyValue, initial_capital = defaultInitialCapital, currency = defaultCurrency, max_lines_count = maxLinesCount, max_labels_count = maxLabelsCount, slippage = defaultSlippage, commission_type = defaultCommissionType, commission_value = defaultCommissionValue, process_orders_on_close = processOrderOnClose, close_entries_rule = closeEntriesRule, linktoseries = isLinkToSeries)
// linktoseries = isLinkToSeries
// >>>>Strategy Settings Ends<<<<

// >>>>Study Settings Begains<<<<
// >>>>Study Settings Ends<<<<



length = input( 14 )
overSold = input( 40 )
overBought = input( 70 )
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, length)
co = crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu = crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
var entryPrice = 0.0
var orderOpen = false
if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co)
        isOrderOpen = orderOpen ? "true" : "false"
        if (not orderOpen)
            entryPrice := price
        strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="Price: " + tostring(price) + " Entry Price: "+ tostring(entryPrice*1.001) + " Order Open?: " + isOrderOpen)
        orderOpen := true
    if (cu and ((entryPrice * 1.001) < price))
        isOrderOpen = orderOpen ? "true" : "false"
        strategy.close("long", comment="Price: " + tostring(price) + " Entry Price: "+ tostring(entryPrice*1.001) + " Order Open?: " + isOrderOpen)
        orderOpen := false
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter placement doesn't matter in your example, because you're using named parameters.

```
strategy(title = scriptLongTitle, shorttitle = scriptShortTitle, overlay = isOverlayEnabled, ...)
```

Named parameters can be given in any sequence you like, so this would be ok too:

```
strategy(overlay = isOverlayEnabled, shorttitle = scriptShortTitle, title = scriptLongTitle, ...)
```

Parameter sequence only matters when you don't use named parameters.
In that case, they need to be entered in the same sequence as the function definition.
So this would work:

```
strategy(scriptLongTitle, scriptShortTitle, isOverlayEnabled, ...)
```

But this would not work:

```
strategy(isOverlayEnabled, scriptShortTitle, scriptLongTitle, ...)
```

You are correct though, that `linktoseries` is missing from both the `study()` and `strategy()` parameter list.
I think they just forgot to make that visible in the parameter list because clearly, that parameter is accepted by Pine.